# Peter pepper plant seeding yellow new leaves

Tags: leaves, seedlings, discoloration

I am using my own built green house to prepare some chili plants for next years gardening season. I have planted various seeds and almost all of them have grown into seedlings. I have noticed that one specific sort of chili plant (peter chili) grows very strange:

- The first pair of leaves was very dark green
- After a day or two the first pair of leaves started to turn lighter and lighter green, to the extent one can see the "veins" of the leaves
- The subsequent pairs of leaves are all almost yellow
- It is still growing nicely, however the leaves are colored weirdly
- Yellowing is worse on newer leaves
- Other seedlings in the same area do not suffer from the same discoloring
- All 4 plants of the same sort look exactly the same

Plants are living a 14/10 hour schedule for light/night and have a constant 28°C. I am using a specific coconut based growth medium that came with the seeds and have also already fertilized it once with tomato/paprika fertilizer (I was thinking Nitrogen deficiency).

Below is a picture of one of the plants. It is hard to tell from the lighting with the phone camera, but the one on the right is much more yellow than the one on the left. Is this normal or what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: I would suspect light deficiency provided it is not root rot. And root rot would be evident pretty soon if it's that. Comment instead of answer because I'm blabbering - I can't back any of this up.

Comment: No I think you were right there with root rot. I think too much humidity + too high heat (the software I wrote had a malfunction in the beginning overheating it). It probably was early enough for some, of the 4 plants 2 died, 1 looks completely normal again and the one in the picture above is starting shift from almost yellow back to a healthy green.